# Windows Server 2008 R2 Slow File Copy

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, filesystems, hp-proliant, raid-controller

I recently installed Windows Standard Server 2008 R2 with SP1 on an HP Proliant ML350 G5.  This server has Sql Server 2008 Express with a few very small databases, and acts as a file and print share server.  There's no antivirus installed.  No Hyper-V installed.  There's two RAID 1+0's configured.  Raid A is two 160Gb drives and has the OS installed on it, Raid B is two 1TB drives and has the file shares.

We noticed right after bringing the server up, and user started to access it, that large file copies over the network would slow the server right down - almost to the point where it wasn't functional.  It's important to note though, that doing file copies not over the network, so from one disk to another or from an external USB to either disk, causes the same problem.  I say that's important to note because this is not a network card/switch/etc problem.

I've been searching through forums and posts for over a day and have found plenty of examples that are similar, but am yet to find a solution.

So far, I've installed HP's Proliant Support Pack and updated everything I could.  I ran HP's Smart Array Configuration Utility. I've tried disabling SMB2.  No luck so far.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are a number of causes than can lead to that: working on a large number of small files, slow or defective hdd, bad storage driver or wrong sata mode, lack of raid controller with backup battery and write cache. You can start with some hdd benchmark and check if sequential and random read and write speeds are the expected ones.

Answer (score 0):

From the Array Configuration Utility, I enabled Physical Drive Write Cache. My server does have redundant power supply, and is obviously protected by UPS so I'm not concerned about data loss. This fixed my problem.